# Все экземпляры классов, загруженные в JVM heap

Tags: java, рефлексия, jvm

Для Java есть куча профайлеров (VisualVM), которые показывают полный список всех загруженных в кучу (heap) экземпляров классов (instances).

Существуют ли способы получить список экземпляров классов, загруженных в JVM heap, посредством java, есть ли какое-то API для этих целей?

И все это для 5-й версии JDK.

Comment: А зачем это делать? Что за анализ вам нужен?

Comment: Пока это только идея. Хочу составить статистику. Сервлет фильтр будет писать лог посещения страниц сайта по времени. А какая-то утилита в отдельном потоке будет каждые 10 секунд показывать какие классы загружены в память (не все классы, а только те. которые важны для статистики). Примерно так.

Comment: А зачем это нужно? Это же бессмыслица просто напросто. Если вам надо утечку найти, так возьмите дамп и посмотрите на него. А если вы какой-то баг хотите поймать, то добавьте логов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте команду [jmap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html#seealso). Из приложения можно вызвать с помощью

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jmap [ option ] pid");
```

**UPD.** Пример:

```
String pid = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0];
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("jmap -histo " + pid);
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Вывод получается в три столбца:

> Size Count Class description
>
> ---
>
> 4473488 44525 char[]
>
> 2663464 21830 *ConstMethodKlass
>
> 1575128 21830 *MethodKlass
>
> 1297600 40550 java.util.HashMap$ValueIterator
>
> 1272064 34452 *SymbolKlass
>
> 1262664 52611 java.lang.String 1129928 2142
>
> byte[] 1042984 1761 *ConstantPoolKlass

Каждую строку можно анализировать с помощью регулярного выражения. Проверять, является ли текущий класс интересующим нас, и тогда вносить данные о нем в вашу статистику.

Насчет профайлеров. Они используют средства, которые описаны [здесь](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/jdk50_ts_guide.pdf), Diagnostics Tools and Options.

Comment: Работает. Но насколько я понимаю способа анализировать подобного рода данные в Java коде нету.

Comment: jmap -histo pid | grep ClassName, например, для unix